# how to say a group of people is more crowded in number compared to another

Tags: word-usage

> ***While male members were generally ______ in the first half of the period, female membership rose considerably to surpass that of males in the ensuing years.***

Should it be:

> predominant in number

> dominant in number

> more crowded

or are none of them correct?

[image]

Comment: There are seven years in the graph, so "first half" and "second half" don't seem to fit the data supplied.  The least bad expression there is the first, 'predominant in number", but it seems very complicated, Why not say, "There were more males members in the first half, but more female members later."

Comment: _Crowded_ is definitely the wrong word. A room or area is crowded when there are a lot of people in it, but we can't say that membership of a club is crowded, because the members are not all physically present at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both for the information!

@JackO'Flaherty Regarding your concern about my usage of "first half" and "second half", I thought the same thing, and that's why I added "generally". Isn't it enough to make it fit?

Comment: @anIELTSlearner Where is the example question found, or are you formulating it?

Comment: Yes, I am formulating it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the statement is to drop **were** in "male members were" and use another verb:

> Males *outnumbered* females...
>
> Male membership *outpaced* female membership ...

But if you wanted to use a simple BE predicate:

> Male membership was *significantly greater* than female membership...